# rails model attribute ensure uniqueness except for certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails, I could restrict certain attribute to be unique within scope but pass on nil or blank. How could I ensure uniqueness but pass on certain value?

I encrypted an attribute, so it's not nil anymore. But I do allow nil for this attribute in the model.

Comment: What do you mean by "Pass on nil or blank"?

Comment: Have you seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914899/rails-validate-uniqueness-only-if-conditional)? You should be able to add any conditional logic you need to using `if: ->{...}`.