# Rails validation if association has value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

In my Rails app I have Content, Fields, and FieldContents.

The associations are:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :field_contents
end

class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :field_contents
end

class FieldContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
  belongs_to :field
end
```

Fields contain columns that describe the field, such as name, required, and validation.

What I want to do is validate the FieldContent using the data from its Field.

So for example:

```
class FieldContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
  belongs_to :field
  # validate the field_content using validation from the field
  validates :content, presence: true if self.field.required == 1
  validates :content, numericality: true if self.field.validation == 'Number'
end
```

However I'm currently getting the error: `undefined method 'field' for #<Class:0x007f9013063c90>` but I'm using RubyMine and the model can see the association fine...

**It would seem `self` is the incorrect thing to use here! What should I be using?
How can I apply the validation based on its parent values?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails validate uniqueness only if conditional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914899/rails-validate-uniqueness-only-if-conditional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) is exactly what you need:

```
class FieldContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
  belongs_to :field
  # with method
  validates :content, presence: true, if: :field_required?
  # with block
  validates :content, numericality: true,
    if: proc { |f| f.field.validation == 'Number' }

  def field_required?
    field.required == 1
  end
end
```

Comment: This is perfect :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Using a string:

`validates :content, presence: true, if: 'self.field.required == 1'`

#### Using a Proc:

`validates :content, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |field_content| field_content.field.required == 1 }`

[This SO answer may be useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914899/rails-validate-uniqueness-only-if-conditional)